# Javascript - Multiplicar, dividir y comparar

Tags: javascript, calculo

Estoy aprendiendo JS y en mi práctica **no consigo hacer que me funcione la primera parte** de mi script.

Tengo 3 inputs ( `#ancho - #fondo - #alto` ), donde escribir **números enteros** para una multiplicación entre ellos, seguido de una división, pero no me funciona, y ni siquiera veo nada en el div `#resultado`

Ejemplo: 20 x 20 x 20 / 4000

En la segunda parte quiero comparar si el valor "`r=`" es mayor o menor al número escrito en el `input #peso`, y en funcion de eso mostrar u ocultar un div, pero si no consigo que la multiplicación y división me funcione, poco podré hacer para comparar luego nada.

Qué estoy haciendo mal aquí...?
Alguna pista...?

---

**VER DEMO EN:** **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pogrx8nw/)**

---

Gracias!

---

**HTML:**

```
<input id="ancho"> <!-- Ejemplo value="22" -->
<input id="fondo"> <!-- Ejemplo value="20" -->
<input id="alto"> <!-- Ejemplo value="16" -->

<input id="peso"> <!-- Ejemplo value="3" -->

<div id="hacercalculo" onclick="calcular();comparar()">Calcular</div>

<!--<div id="resultado"></div>-->

<div id="uno">1</div> <!-- oculto via css / display:none -->
<div id="dos">2</div> <!-- oculto via css / display:none -->
<div id="tres">3</div> <!-- oculto via css / display:none -->
```

**jQuery:**

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
```

**Script:**

```
function calcular(){
  v1 = document.getElementById("ancho").value;
  v2 = document.getElementById("fondo").value;
  v3 = document.getElementById("alto").value;
  
  r = v1*v2*v3/4000;
  
  //document.getElementById("resultado").value = r;
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = r;
};
```

**Ahora busco la comparación para mostrar el div #uno:** (no me funciona)

```
    function comparar() {

    var camp1= document.getElementById("resultado");
    var camp2= document.getElementById("peso");

    //if (camp1.value >= 0 && camp2.value <= 3) {
    //if (camp1.innerText >= 0 && camp2.innerText <= 3) {
    //if (camp1.innerHTML >= 0 && camp2.value <= 3) {
      
      if (camp1.innerText >= 0 && camp2.value <= 3) {

        $("#uno").show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba document.getElementById("resultado").innetHTML = r;

Comment: No es value sino innerText para modificar el texto de una etiqueta que no sea un input como en este caso un div

Comment: Y con el cambio funcióna o que ocurre?

Comment: Muchas gracias compis, funciona de maravilla. Edité mi post ( ocultando `#resultado` ) para no mostrarlo, y ahora estoy buscando comparar el valor del resultado con el valor escrito en el input `#peso` para que si resultado  `<= 0 && <= 3 ` pueda ver (  `.show` ) el div  `#uno `, y así con las siguientes comparaciones entre el resultado y el valor numerico de  `#peso `. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo..? Gracias!

Comment: @BetaM acabo de editar mi pregunta, y de responder la ayuda con otra (como dice el post, el script debe cumplir 2 partes.

Comment: Y estás usando jQuery?

Comment: @BetaM Si. 2.2.4 ... El script de calcular funciona perfectamente, lo que **no consigo** es mostrar el div `#uno - #dos - #tres - ...` con las función de comparar. Mira el post, está editado.

Comment: @Pablo_Web, el problema que tenes ahora es el mismo de antes `resultado` no es `input` (_no podes usar `.value`_) y ademas esta comentado (_es decir, no existe_) y `peso` no lo calculas (_o no las has incluido_)

Comment: @Marcos A `#peso` lo he comentado en el post para explicar que no quiero mostrarlo. Sobre `#peso` aquí es el usuario el que escribe el valor (ejemplo 2), y es lo que quiero comparar con `#resultado` ... Entonces si `#resultado` no es un input, ¿cómo debo arreglar el script? (soy demasiado novato, se nota). Gracias

Comment: @Pablo_Web, utilizando lo que te comentaron previamente, es decir, `.innerText` o en su defecto `.innerHTML`

Comment: @Marcos ... He realizado los cambios (**y editado el post**), pero no consigo mostrar el div `#uno` si el resultado es (ejemplo) 1 y el valor escrito en `#peso` es 2. Algo no me funciona y no puedo saber qué es... :( ...

Comment: @Pablo_Web, `peso` es un `input` por lo que tenes que usar `.value`. ¿Estas seguro de que has incluido `jQuery` en tu `HTML`?

Comment: @Marcos ... Si jQuery 2.2.4 ... Todo funciona, excepto la comparación. No sé qué hago mal, la verdad (**he vuelto a editar el post, con todos los cambios**). ¿Tendrá algo que ver que algunos resultados son con decimales, y no lo estoy teniendo en cuenta...? Me pierdo, la verdad...

Comment: @Pablo_Web, voy a crear una respuesta solo para demostrar que debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una respuesta para mostrar que podrías hacer para dejarlo funcionando.

```js
function calcular(){
  v1 = document.getElementById("ancho").value;
  v2 = document.getElementById("fondo").value;
  v3 = document.getElementById("alto").value;
  
  r = v1*v2*v3/4000;

  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = r;
};

// Ahora (con la función "comparar"), buscamos comparar entre el resultado de la operacion de la función "calcular" y el valor numérico que el usuario escriba en el input "peso".

// Si la condición IF se cumple, mostrar el div #uno

function comparar() {

    //var camp1= document.getElementById("resultado");
    var camp1= document.getElementById("resultado");
    var camp2= document.getElementById("peso");

    //if (camp1.value >= 0 && camp2.value <= 5) {
    //if (camp1.innerHTML >= 0 && camp2.innerHTML <= 5) {
    if (camp1.innerHTML >= 0 && camp2.value <= 3) {

        $("#uno").show();
    }
};
```

```css
body{text-align:center}

p{margin:15px auto}

#uno,#dos,#tres {display:none;width:50px;margin:0 auto;padding:5px 10px;background:#000;color:#fff;text-align:center}

input{display:block;margin:15px auto 5px;border:1px solid #999;background:#ff0;padding:6px 0;text-align:center}

#peso{background:#e6e6e6}

#resultado{width:130px;height:40px;margin:20px auto 5px;line-height:40px;color:#fff;background:green}

#hacercalculo {width:130px;height:40px;margin:15px auto;line-height:40px;color:#fff;background:red;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ancho">
Ancho

<input id="fondo">
Fondo

<input id="alto">
Alto

<input id="peso">
Peso

<p>-----------------</p>

<div id="resultado"></div>
Resultado

<p>-----------------</p>

<div id="hacercalculo" onclick="calcular();comparar()">CALCULAR</div>

<div id="uno">1</div>
<div id="dos">2</div>
<div id="tres">3</div>
```

Comment: Tu script sí que funciona, pero el mío (al menos el comparador), no lo hace (**el calculador sí funciona perfectamente**). Es el comparador lo que me trae de cabeza. No encuentro el error de mi código, la verdad...

Comment: Publiqué una **DEMO** de mi post en JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rdaon2Lz/

Comment: @Pablo_Web en tu demo, tenes 2 errores. El primero es que nunca estas llamando a la funcion `comparar()` y el segundo es que en dicha funcion `camp1` y `camp2` son los valores finales, por lo hacer `if (camp1.innerHTML >= 0 && camp2.value <= 3)` es un error, deberia ser `if (camp1 >= 0 && camp2 <= 3)`. Actualice mi respuesta para darte una posible solución

Comment: Sí, estoy puliendo errores. Como digo en el post, soy un novato (pero con ganas) ... :) ... Gracias

Comment: @Pablo_Web, no hay porque sentirse mal, todos pasamos por lo mismo. Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!